# rotating coordinate systems sympy

Tags: sympy, coordinate-systems

I'm a complete beginner with sympy, so it may be I'm overlooking something basic. I would like to rotate my coordinate system so I can build a hyperbola in standard position and then transform it to the arbitrary case. First I set up my equation:

```
> x, y, a, b, theta = symbols('x y a b theta')
> f = Eq(x ** 2/a ** 2 - y ** 2/b ** 2, 1)
> f1 = f.subs({a: 5, b: 10})
> f1
> x**2/25 - y**2/100 == 1
```

Next I want to rotate it, which I try to do by using a sub:

```
> f1.subs({x: x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta), y: x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta)})
> -(x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta))**2/100 + (x*cos(theta) - (x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta))*sin(theta))**2/25 == 1
```

But that doesn't work because apparently the substitution for x is made before the one for y, and the value of x substituted in is already updated. There must be some way to do this substitution, right?

Or is there a better tool than sympy to do this in? Once I get my hyperbolas I will want to find points of intersection between different ones.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **simultaneous=True** in the **.subs( )** method to force SymPy to replace all variables at once (practically, SymPy internally creates temporary variables, proceeds with the substitution, then restores the old variables).

```
In [13]: f1.subs({x: x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta),
                  y: x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta)}, simultaneous=True)
Out[13]: 
                   2                        2    
  (x⋅sin(θ) + y⋅cos(θ))    (x⋅cos(θ) - y⋅sin(θ))     
- ────────────────────── + ────────────────────── = 1
           100                       25
```

Otherwise use *.xreplace( ... )* instead of *.subs( ... )*

```
In [11]: f1.xreplace({x: x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta), 
                      y: x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta)})
Out[11]: 
                       2                        2    
  (x⋅sin(θ) + y⋅cos(θ))    (x⋅cos(θ) - y⋅sin(θ))     
- ────────────────────── + ────────────────────── = 1
           100                       25
```

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to use temporary symbols :

```
x_temp, y_temp = symbols('x_temp y_temp')
f1.subs({x: x_temp*cos(theta) - y_temp*sin(theta), y: x_temp*sin(theta) + y_temp*cos(theta)}).subs({x_temp: x, y_temp: y})

> -(x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta))**2/100 + (x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta))**2/25 == 1
```

[I think sympy can do what you want. There is a `polysys` modules in `sympy.solvers` :](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/_modules/sympy/solvers/polysys.html)

```
"""
Solve a system of polynomial equations.

Examples
========

>>> from sympy import solve_poly_system
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y

>>> solve_poly_system([x*y - 2*y, 2*y**2 - x**2], x, y)
[(0, 0), (2, -sqrt(2)), (2, sqrt(2))]

"""
```